# Optaplanner shows zero hard constraint violations in the debug log but shows violations when I use SolutionManager to explain the scores

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

On running the optimization model , the optaplanner log printed on the terminal shows ZERO hard constraint violations "best score (0hard/0medium/-1056704soft)". After this I printed the hard score of the calculated solution and it printed ZERO correctly. However in the next line of the program, when I try do the score explanation using the SolutionManager library, it shows -1hard/0medium/0soft for a particular constraint.

On checking the solution, I realized that there was actually a hard constraint violation. Can anyone explain why this violation was not shown in the initial logs and why did the hard score print as ZERO ?

Answer (score 2):

Smells like **Score Corruption** in OptaPlanner or [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork/).

Locally turn on `environmentMode=FAST_ASSERT` (or `FULL_ASSERT`) in your `application.properties` or `SolverConfig`. Do not commit that change. Run it 10 times as long to reach the same point. That will flush out any score corruption the moment it occurs and should give you a clue as to which constraint is involved. Then part 2 starts: figuring out why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have turned on environmentMode=FULL_ASSERT and ran the program. In the first run itself, it shows the constraint involved. The log shows the following : "The corrupted scoreDirector has 1 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing. Maybe there is a bug in the score constraints of those ConstraintMatch(s).
Maybe a score constraint doesn't select all the entities it depends on, but finds some through a reference in a selected entity. This corrupts incremental score calculation, because the constraint is not re-evaluated if such a non-selected entity changes."

Comment: Can you help me with the second part ? I am working on a task-resource assignment problem.  The main Planning entity (TaskAssignment.java) contains two planning variables - startTime (of task) and Crew member (assigned to task). I have another planning entity in CrewMember.java that contains an inverse relation shadow variable to  the crewMember planning variable in TaskAssignment.java.
The problematic constraint penalizes the case where a crew member is assigned more than 1 task at a given time. Can you suggest how to create a constraint to do this in the correct way ?

Comment: `The corrupted scoreDirector has 1 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing` it actually says which one is missing too, on the next line. It says which constraint causes the score corruption.